# How to group by nested list of dictionary key in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tough time grouping id(s) based on a nested list of dictionary key

Below code is working for me to group the ids and st values based on location

```
null=''
dataset={"users": [
    {"id": 20, "loc": "Chicago", "st":"4", "sectors": [{"sname": "Retail"}, {"sname": "Manufacturing"}, {"sname": null}]}, 
    {"id": 21, "loc": "Frankfurt", "st":"4", "sectors": [{"sname": null}]}, 
    {"id": 22, "loc": "Berlin", "st":"6", "sectors": [{"sname": "Manufacturing"}, {"sname": "Banking"},{"sname": "Agri"}]}, 
    {"id": 23, "loc": "Chicago", "st":"2", "sectors": [{"sname": "Banking"}, {"sname": "Agri"}]},
    {"id": 24, "loc": "Bern", "st":"1", "sectors": [{"sname": "Retail"}, {"sname": "Agri"}]},
    {"id": 25, "loc": "Bern", "st":"4", "sectors": [{"sname": "Retail"}, {"sname": "Agri"}, {"sname": "Banking"}]}
    ]}

byloc = lambda x: x['loc']

it = (
    (loc, list(user_grp))
    for loc, user_grp in itertools.groupby(
        sorted(dataset['users'], key=byloc), key=byloc
    )
)
fs_loc = [
    {'loc': loc, 'ids': [{'id':x['id'],'st':x['st']} for x in grp], 'count': len(grp)}
    for loc, grp in it
]

print(fs_loc)
```

fs_loc gives me the list of ids and respective st values as below (Along with the id count)

```
[
    {"loc": "Chicago","count":2,"ids": [{"id":"20","st":"4"}, {"id":"23","st":"2"}]}, 
    {"loc": "Bern","count":2,"ids": [{"id":"24","st":"1"}, {"id":"25","st":"4"}]}, 
    {"loc": "Frankfurt","count":1,"ids": [{"id":"21","st":"4"}]}, 
    {"loc": "Berlin","count":1,"ids": [{"id":"21","st":"4"}]}    
]
```

Now, am trying to group by sname from sectors - I tried below code, which fails.. Couldn't figure out on how to achieve the result as below -

**Desired Result:**

```
[
    {"sname": "Retail","count":3,"ids": [{"id":"20","st":"4"}, {"id":"24","st":"1"}, {"id":"25","st":"4"}]}, 
    {"sname": "Manufacturing","count":2,"ids": [{"id":"20","st":"4"}, {"id":"22","st":"6"}]}, 
    {"sname": "Banking","count":2,"ids": [{"id":"22","st":"6"},{"id":"23","st":"2"}]}, 
    {"sname": "Agri","count":4,"ids": [{"id":"22","st":"6"},{"id":"23","st":"2"},{"id":"24","st":"1"},{"id":"25","st":"4"}]}    
]
```

I tried below code, it doesn't work for nested list of dictionary key -

```
bysname = lambda x: x['sectors'][0]['sname']

it = (
    (sname, list(user_grp))
    for sname, user_grp in itertools.groupby(
        sorted(dataset['users'], key=bysname), key=bysname
    )
)
fs_sname= [
    {'sname': sname, 'ids': [{'id':x['id'],'st':x['st']} for x in grp], 'count': len(grp)}
    for sname, grp in it
]

print(fs_sname)
```

**EDIT-**
Above code is working, but it is considering only the first item of sectors list. i.e., it gives below result -

```
[
    {"sname": "","count":1,"ids": [{"id":"21","st":"4"}]}, 
    {"sname": "Manufacturing","count":1,"ids": [{"id":"22","st":"6"}]}, 
    {"sname": "Banking","count":1,"ids": [{"id":"23","st":"2"}]}, 
    {"sname": "Retail","count":3,"ids": [{"id":"20","st":"4"},{"id":"24","st":"1"},{"id":"25","st":"4"}]}    
]
```

How can I achieve as mentioned in Desired result?

Comment: I don't understand what your desired result is. Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: i already added it.. could u pls chk highlighted ?

Comment: That can be ignored.. I will have handle it before data preparation

Comment: `x['sectors'][0]` is of type `dict` which is an unhashable type.  My guess is that, if you are getting different results between using `loc` as the key and using this,  `groupby` might be getting thrown off by this unhashability.  You could try having your `lambda` extract  `x['sectors'][0]['sname']` instead...?

Comment: Thanks jez! It is working but it considers only the first item from the list.. i.e., For retail, it gives 3 id's.. For Manufacturing it gives 1.. For Banking it gives 1 and same with Agri.. How can I loop through the sectors, such that it considers for all ?

Comment: Does the ordering of the sectors matter?   you could have your `bysname` lambda return `tuple( sec['secname'] for sec in x['sector'])`  if so, or you could add make it `tuple( sorted( sec['secname'] for sec in x['sector'] ) )` if not

Comment: That groups your result by each unique *combination* of sectors, but then I'm not 100% sure that's what you want. You'll need a different strategy if you want to query "all records for which Retail is *among* the sectors, followed by all records for which Agri is *among* the sectors, etc..." because that's not a `groupby` operation (might return the same record in more than one group)

Comment: I tried this, it gives me combination of snames.. and count is 1 for all the lists. Not sure how I can achieve the required result

Comment: Could you please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work - adapt the `summarize` function as needed

```
allsectornames = set( sec['sname'] for record in dataset['users'] for sec in record['sectors'] )

summarize = lambda record:  record[ 'id' ]   # customize this to return whatever details you want (even just return the whole record itself if you prefer)

result = [
    {
        'sname':sname,
        'count':len(matches),
        'matches':[ summarize( match ) for match in matches ]
    }
    for sname in allsectornames
    for matches in [[
        record for record in dataset['users'] if sname in [ sec['sname'] for sec in record['sectors'] ]
    ]]
]

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jez! I added st field to get the set of id,st